# Contribute an "editorAction" via org.eclipse.ui.menus extension point

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

In many documents like [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-3.3menu/index.html) it is described, that old extension points `org.eclipse.ui.actionSets`, `org.eclipse.ui.viewActions`, `org.eclipse.ui.editorActions`, and `org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus` from Eclipse 3.2 were replaced by the new `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point in Eclipse 3.3.

So my simple question: 
How do I use the new extension point `org.eclipse.ui.menus` to contribute to an editorAction toolbar (`org.eclipse.ui.editorActions`) ?

I tried stuff like the following in many different `locationURI` values but it never worked.

```
   <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution locationURI="toolbar:my.editor.id">
         <command
               commandId="my.command.id"
               icon="icons/somicon.gif"
               label="Do my command"
               style="push">
         </command>
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
```

My command never shows up and I dont get any feedback in the console. So what is the correct property for `locationURI`, to get my command in there??

The command works on other toolbars, it also works via the old extension point (with modifications of the command class).

Why I need the new extension piont? 
Because it not only supports commands, but also controls, where you can contribute more than a simple button.

**Final update**

The solution below intended to replace the functionality from editorActions extension point. Due to the bug mentioned in the answers last comment, that replacement is not really useful. 
Anyhow accepted...

Comment: Maybe that complete editorAction toolbar and its concept is deprecated and the mechanism, explained by katsharp should be used. Any official confirmation towards that thought would be nice ...

Comment: If you want official confirmation you should probably ask on the Eclipse newsgroups/forums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to contribute to the main toolbar in Eclipse using this locationURI:

```
locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar?after=additions"
```

So, for example, to contribute my command to the toolbar only when my editor is active:

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
  <menuContribution
      locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar?after=additions">
     <toolbar
           id="mytoolbar.id"
           label="my toolbar">
        <command
              commandId="command.id"
              icon="icons/sample.gif"
              id="mytoolbar.command.id"
              label="Do my command"
              style="push">
           <visibleWhen
                 checkEnabled="false">
                     <with
                         variable="activePartId">
                          <equals
                             value="my.editor.id">
                          </equals>
                     </with>
          </visibleWhen>
        </command>
     </toolbar>
  </menuContribution>
</extension>
```

Where command.id is the id of my command.

Comment: thank you for that version. But it is not the editorAction toolbar, which gets completely hidden when the active editor is not the one specified. And I would have to add that to all of my commands.

Comment: What do you mean by editorAction toolbar, is that a section of the main toolbar?

Comment: it is a separate toolbar which holds editor actions. it gets shown when the editor is active and it gets hidden when the editor is inactive. all that showing and hiding is done automatically for all actions inside that toolbar.

Comment: This creates a toolbar (mytoolbar.id), you can then add each of your commands to this. There is a visibleWhen on the toolbar element, however this bug - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=201589 details it not working. So, yes with this implementation you'd have to have a visibleWhen on each command.